# Heroku SSL DNS Endpoint not resolving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

I'm having the issue that my CNAME that points to a herokussl.com SSL endpoint refuses to resolve, or seemingly even be propagated by the DNS servers, but yet seems to work fine for the regular herokuapp.com name. I bought the domain name from whois.com, and their support claims the error is on heroku's end or my entering the url but I'm not so sure. My certificate seems fine. Tech details below, thanks for any and all help!

Details:

```
CNAMES:

deez.chrtwt.org -> sleepy-garden-8448.herokuapp.com Active   **Works**
www.chrtwt.org  -> gifu-3664.herokussl.com Active  **Does not resolve**

pmarx$ heroku certs
Endpoint                 Common Name(s)  Expires               Trusted
-----------------------  --------------  --------------------  -------
gifu-3664.herokussl.com  www.chrtwt.org  2015-01-27 23:59 UTC  True

pmarx$ heroku certs:info
Fetching SSL Endpoint gifu-3664.herokussl.com info for sleepy-garden-8448... done
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.chrtwt.org
Expires At:     2015-01-27 23:59 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/ST=Nevada/L=Las Vegas/O=Charitweet LLC/CN=www.chrtwt.org
Starts At:      2014-01-27 00:00 UTC
Subject:        /C=US/ST=Nevada/L=Las Vegas/O=Charitweet LLC/CN=www.chrtwt.org
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.

pmarx$ heroku domains
=== sleepy-garden-8448 Domain Names
deez.chrtwt.org
sleepy-garden-8448.herokuapp.com
www.chrtwt.org
www.pbridge.org
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue? Please share how did you debug the issue.

I may have a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611057/amazon-route-53-heroku-app-not-accessible-from-certain-places-what-to-do